# Phosphate group acidic or not?

Tags: acid-base

I would like to ask whether or not the "Phosphate Functional Group" itself is acidic. I understand that the compound Phosphoric Acid is very acidic, with several hydrogens. However the Phopshate itself lacks hydrogens to donate. Please clear up any misudnerstandings I am having right now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi and welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Visit the [help] to learn more about it.

Answer (score 1):

No, the phosphate functional group, $\ce{P(O)(OR)_3}$, itself is not acidic. Only protic phosphates are acidic. Phosphates that aren't phosphoric acids (i.e. $\ce{P(O)(OH)_{x}(OR)_{3-x}}$) are actually Lewis bases. The carbonyl oxygen is able to coordinate metals and other Lewis acids.

Comment: Right, but doesn't quite go far enough. In aqueous solution the phosphate ion itself is actually basic, not acidic. Thus $$ \ce{PO4^{3−} + H2O -> HPO4^{2−} + OH^{-}}$$

Comment: OP asked about the phosphate functional group. If asking about the phosphate (tribasic) anion, then what MaxW said is correct.

Comment: Curious but pK2 of phosphate is 7.198 according to Wikipedia which would make the $\ce{HPO3^{2-}}$ slightly basic too. but all the second ionization of all(?) $\ce{R-PO(OH)2}$ compounds seems to be acidic. (I'd wonder if there isn't some weird molecule where the second ionization pKa would be more than 7 in aqueous solution.)

Comment: I believe you meant $\ce{HPO^{2-}_4}$.

Comment: absolutely. thanks for that correction and it should be $\ce{R-O-PO(OH)2}$.